# How to use BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper to map a subset of fields?

Tags: spring-batch

I have a Spring batch application where `BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper` is used to map fields using a prototype object. However, the CSV file that is being read (via a `FlatFileItemReader`) contains one (indicator) field that determines the mapping of another field. If the indicator field has a value of Y, then the value of the another field should be mapped to property `foo` otherwise it should be mapped to property `bar`.

I know that I can use a custom `FieldSetMapper` to do this, but then I have to code the mapping all of the other fields (of which there are a quite a few). Alternatively, I could do this post reading via an `ItemProcessor` but then my domain (prototype) object must have a property representing the indicator field (which I prefer not to do since it is not really part of the business domain).

Is it possible to perhaps use a custom `FieldSetMapper` to only map these custom fields and delegate the other mappings to `BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper`? Or is there some other better way to solve for this?

Here is my current attempt to use a custom `FieldSetMapper` and delegate to `BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper`:

```java
    public class DelegatedFieldSetMapper extends BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<MyProtoClass> {
            
        @Override
        public MyProtoClass mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {       
            String indicator = fieldSet.readString("indicator");
            Properties fieldProperties = fieldSet.getProperties();
            
            if (indicator.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                fieldProperties.put("test.foo", fieldSet.readString("value");
            } else {
                fieldProperties.put("test.bar", fieldSet.readString("value");
            }
            
            fieldProperties.remove("indicator");
            Set<Object> keys = fieldProperties.keySet();
            List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();      
            for (Object key : keys) {
                names.add((String) key);
                values.add((String) fieldProperties.getProperty((String) key));
            }
            DefaultFieldSet domainObjectFieldSet = new DefaultFieldSet(names.toArray(new String[names.size()]), values.toArray(new String[values.size()]));     
            return super.mapFieldSet(domainObjectFieldSet);
        }
        
    }
```

However, a `FlatFileParseException` is thrown. The relevant parts of the batch config class are as follows:

```java
    @Configuration
    @EnableBatchProcessing
    public class BatchConfiguration { 
            
        @Value("${file}")
        private File file;
            
        @Bean
        @Scope("prototype")
        public MyProtoClass () {
            return new MyProtoClass();
        }
        
        @Bean
        public ItemReader<MyProtoClass> reader(LineMapper<MyProtoClass> lineMapper) {
            FlatFileItemReader<MyProtoClass> flatFileItemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<MyProtoClass>();
            flatFileItemReader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(file));
            final int NUMBER_OF_HEADER_LINES = 1;
            flatFileItemReader.setLinesToSkip(NUMBER_OF_HEADER_LINES);
            flatFileItemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper);
            return flatFileItemReader;
        }
        
        @Bean 
        public LineMapper<MyProtoClass> lineMapper(LineTokenizer lineTokenizer, FieldSetMapper<MyProtoClass> fieldSetMapper) {
            DefaultLineMapper<MyProtoClass> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<MyProtoClass>();
            lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);
            lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetMapper);
            return lineMapper;
        }
        
        @Bean
        public LineTokenizer lineTokenizer() {
            DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();        
            lineTokenizer.setNames(new String[] {"value", "test.bar", "test.foo", "indicator"});
            return lineTokenizer;
        }
        
        @Bean
        public FieldSetMapper<MyProtoClass> fieldSetMapper(PropertyEditor emptyStringToNullPropertyEditor) {
            BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<MyProtoClass> fieldSetMapper = new DelegatedFieldSetMapper();
            fieldSetMapper.setPrototypeBeanName("myProtoClass");
            Map<Class<String>, PropertyEditor> customEditors = new HashMap<Class<String>, PropertyEditor>();
            customEditors.put(String.class, emptyStringToNullPropertyEditor);
            fieldSetMapper.setCustomEditors(customEditors);
            return fieldSetMapper;
    
        }
```

Finally, the CSV flat file look like this:

```
value,bar,foo,indicator
abc,,,y
xyz,,,n
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's say that BatchWorkObject is the class to be mapped.
Here's a sample code in Spring Boot style that needs only your custom logic to be added.

```
   new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<BatchWorkObject>(){
       {
        this.setTargetType(BatchWorkObject.class);
        }

    @Override
        public BatchWorkObject mapFieldSet(FieldSet fs)
                throws BindException {
            BatchWorkObject tmp= super.mapFieldSet(fs);
            // your custom code here
            return tmp;
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

The code actually accomplishes what is desired except for one issue that results in the FlatFileParseException. The `DelegatedFieldSetMapper` contains the issue as follows:

```
DefaultFieldSet domainObjectFieldSet = new DefaultFieldSet(names.toArray(new String[names.size()]), values.toArray(new String[values.size()]));
```

To resolve, change to:

```
DefaultFieldSet domainObjectFieldSet = new DefaultFieldSet(values.toArray(new String[values.size()]), names.toArray(new String[names.size()]));
```

Comment: Although this resolves the issue, if anyone has a better / more concise way to accomplish the stated goals of the OP, I will mark that as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Write your own `FieldSetMapper` with a set of prepared delegates inside.
Those delegates are pre-built for every different kind of fields mapping.
In your object route to correct delegate based on indicator field (with a [`Classifier`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/2.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/classify/Classifier.html), for example).
I can't see any other way, but this solution is quite easy and straightforward  to maintain.

Comment: Could you please provide some sample code describing this approach? I believe in your approach that the delegates could be `FieldSetMapper`s such as `BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper`. Then in the `mapFieldSet` method of the custom (main) `FieldSetMapper`, it would call `mapFieldSet` of the delegate `FieldSetMapper`s.

Comment: You right. You can use a switch to route to right mapper or just use a `Classifier` (a PatternMatchingClassifier can be the right choice). I can't give you some code because I haven't spare time, but it is easy to write.

Answer (score 0):

Processing based on the input format/data can be done using a custom implementation of ItemProcessor which is either changing values in the same entity (that was populated by IteamReader) or creates a new one output entity.